# Django-password-reset app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I am trying to use django password reset app whose usage steps are here,

http://django-password-reset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

but I'm unable to understand its documentation, specially the 3rd step which is

> Link to the password reset page: {% url "password_reset_recover" %}

What steps should I follow to use this app, or is there any alternative password reset app, which have clear documentation

Thanks

Comment: You know what is django url when it comes to template? That is exactly what it says. If you have a button with password reset, that action should have a url template to `password_reset_recover`. So: `Link to the password reset page: {% url "password_reset_recover" %}`

Comment: That is what I'm not getting How do i use it? Suppose i have button 
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
WHere do i put it inside this.

I have not used url tag before

Comment: Consider, you have a `<a ..>` link that has a password recover, then did you know with `href` pointing to `{% url "password_reset_recover" %}`

Comment: okay, so button click event handler can take a url of the above.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag)

URL
Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view function and optional parameters. Any special characters in the resulting path will be encoded using iri_to_uri().

This is a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by having to hard-code URLs in your templates:

{% url 'some-url-name' %}

In short, this is a way to map the urls from your urls.py to your templates

For alternatives there is always [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) when it comes to handling users